# Javascript namespacing - updating an an array value from an object literal notation (OLN)

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm using OLN for some basic namespacing in a few javascript files. The "logical hierarchy" of those files is something like this:

```
-main.js
  -somefile.js
  -otherfile.js
  -....
```

main.js manages stuff that all pages need, but then depending on the specific page loaded somefile.js or otherfile.js might be loaded (or neither).

In main.js, this is the syntax:

**main.js**

```
var mainjs = { 
    someobjects: [baz],
    // more stuff
}
```

Depending on what page is loaded, other javascript files are loaded. They might add objects to that list, like so:

**somefile.js**

```
let foo;
let bar;
$(function() {                          
    console.log( " somefile.js ready!" ); 
    mainjs.someobjects = mainjs.someobjects.concat([foo, bar])
}
```

If I look in the console after page load, I can see that within `mainjs.someobjects`, I have those 3 objects. "baz" is defined and the 2 others I added are "undefined". That's fine.

However, when I later initialized those 2 objects from `somefile.js` (user clicks something), then in the console I can see that `foo` & `bar` are both defined. However, in `mainjs.someobjects`, the 2 objects are still undefined.

I thought those would be passed as reference, but apparently I was wrong. Basically the issue I'm trying to address is that I have a few different `somefile.js` which may create different objects (dataTables actually) but they fetch the data (ajax calls) only when the tab that contains them is shown. Then I need to adjust the columns widths based on the data. A known issue with datatables, when the html is created before the datatable is populated. A call to table.columns.adjust() is needed for that to happen.

So:

- Why are my variables in `mainjs` still undefined and who I can change my structure so that when those variables are later assigned to objects, they actually reference the object?
- Alternatively another way to ensure my datatables are ajusted. However I'd rather NOT have to build a completely different structure to make that happen. I guess I could delegate the column adjusting to the lower-level files where they are defined...

Comment: What's "OLN"? Object Literal Notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought those would be passed as reference, but apparently I was wrong.

Yes, JavaScript is a purely pass-by-value language, other than something JavaScript native modules ("ESM") do.

It sounds to me like you want to use ESM. In ESM, when you export a module-level *binding* (loosely, "variable") and another module imports it, the other module has a *read only **live** binding* that links it to the original exported one. That means that when the module that imported it uses it, it sees the then-current value of the source binding (not the value it had when it was exported).

So if you were using ESM and did:

```
export let foo;
export let bar;

// ...code here that asynchronously or periodically updates `foo` and/or `bar`...
```

Then a module importing them:

```
import {foo, bar} from "./some-module.js";
```

...will see the current values of `foo` and `bar` via those live bindings.

---

If you don't want to use ESM for some reason, you can export an *object* with properties for `foo` and `bar`, and have the other code using that exported object. Since the object is stable (we don't replace it with a different object), code using it can reliably access its `foo` and `bar` properties and see their current values.

Basically, in `somefile.js`:

```
const meaningfulName = {
    foo: undefined, // Or some more meaningful initial value
    bar: undefined, // Or some more meaningful initial value
};
$(function() {                          
    console.log( " somefile.js ready!" ); 
    // Just FWIW, I probably woudn't use an array for this, I'd use an object
    mainjs.someobjects = mainjs.someobjects.concat(meaningfulName);
}
```

Then code using that object would use its `foo` and `bar` properties, and always see the current value of them.

Comment: Oh..... so basically, my ONL strategy was fine for basic namespacing of functions which is mostly what I had been using for. But it is NOT adapted to my current needs for variables references... Am I right in thinking that I COULD keep the rest of my ONL strucutre (which works fine) and just parallele to that use ESM to manage those variables? Or would that be ill-advised?

Comment: I think that's up to you. If you want to keep your current structure, using objects with `foo` and `bar` properties might work better for you, and then you can migrate to ESM later. (That said, I **really** like proper modules and encourage switching to them. :-) )

Comment: Yeah I mean just reading up on ESM and it does seem like overall what you'd want to get at if you do enough front-end dev. I'm not sure I can/want to get into that RIGHT NOW that being said. Thanks for the alternative suggestion and yes, mostly likely next time I start something I'll consider esm from the beginning. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Happy coding! :-D